# CLLocationManger for Region Delegate methods not Invoked

Tags: iphone, ios

I have Requirement where i have to set the **radius** for `CLLocation`. I have written the Code in `viewDidLoad` method as:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    [locationManager setDelegate:self];    
    [locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];
    [locationManager setDistanceFilter:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    CLLocationDegrees latitude = 37.33036720;
    CLLocationDegrees longitude = -122.02923067;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D center = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude);
    CLLocationDistance radius = 100.0;
    CLRegion *region = [[CLRegion alloc]initCircularRegionWithCenter:center radius:radius identifier:@"Apple"];
    [locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:region];
}
```

And the delegate methods are as follows:

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didStartMonitoringForRegion:(CLRegion *)region{
            NSLog(@"didStartMonitoringForRegion %@", region);    
    }

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region  {
            NSLog(@"didEnterRegion %@", region);    
   }

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didExitRegion:(CLRegion *)region  {
    NSLog(@"didExitRegion %@", region);        
}
```

I have taken some static location from *Location Log*. But the Methods are **NOT invoked**.

Comment: try `retain`ing your `locationManager`.

Answer (score 0):

May be your region radius is so small, there is no chance you will get an accurate pickup. Try to expand it from half meter.

You can also try setting the accuracy as well, but the radius is your main issue I'm almost certain.

OR May be

When testing your region monitoring code on a device, realize that region events may not happen immediately after a region boundary is crossed. To prevent spurious notifications, `iOS` doesn't deliver region notifications until certain threshold conditions are met. Specifically, the user’s location must cross the region boundary and move away from that boundary by a min distance and remain at that min distance for at least 20-30 seconds before the notifications are reported.

The specific threshold distances are determined by the hardware and the location technologies that are currently available. For example, if Wi-Fi is disabled, region monitoring is significantly less accurate. However, for testing purposes, you can assume that the minimum distance is approximately 200 meters.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25178981/geo-fencing-didenterregion-and-didexitregion-methods-not-called.Can you please check this and help me to find out the issue