# Geo-Fencing didEnterRegion and didExitRegion methods not called?

Tags: objective-c, ios7, xcode5, geofencing

Hi Guys Am working on Geo-Fencing! Location manager didDetermineState is calling properly but when i entered region didEnterRegion and didExitRegion never been invoked.

Here my code is

```
   **ViewController.m**

GeofenceMonitor  * gfm = [GeofenceMonitor sharedObj];
NSMutableDictionary * fence1 = [NSMutableDictionary new];
[fence1 setValue:@"office" forKey:@"identifier"];
[fence1 setValue:@"13.04765701" forKey:@"latitude"];
[fence1 setValue:@"80.18752289" forKey:@"longitude"];
[fence1 setValue:@"100" forKey:@"radius"];
[fence1 setValue:@"11" forKey:@"id"];

NSMutableDictionary * fence2 = [NSMutableDictionary new];
[fence2 setValue:@"axis baank end" forKey:@"identifier"];
[fence2 setValue:@"13.04705048" forKey:@"latitude"];
[fence2 setValue:@"80.18778229" forKey:@"longitude"];
[fence2 setValue:@"100" forKey:@"radius"];
[fence2 setValue:@"12" forKey:@"id"];


if([gfm checkLocationManager])
{
    [gfm addGeofence:fence1];
    [gfm addGeofence:fence2];
    [gfm findCurrentFence];
}
```

**GeofenceMonitor.m**

```
     -(id) init
   {
       self = [super init];
        if(self)
         {

    arr_region=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
     self.locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = NO;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];


}
return self;
   }


 +(GeofenceMonitor *) sharedObj
 {

static GeofenceMonitor * shared =nil;

static dispatch_once_t onceTocken;
dispatch_once(&onceTocken, ^{
    shared = [[GeofenceMonitor alloc] init];
});
return shared;
     }

   - (CLRegion*)dictToRegion:(NSDictionary*)dictionary
   {
     NSString *identifier = [dictionary valueForKey:@"id"];
   CLLocationDegrees latitude = [[dictionary valueForKey:@"latitude"] doubleValue];
   CLLocationDegrees longitude =[[dictionary valueForKey:@"longitude"] doubleValue];
   CLLocationCoordinate2D centerCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude,           longitude);
  CLLocationDistance regionRadius = [[dictionary valueForKey:@"radius"] doubleValue];

if(regionRadius > locationManager.maximumRegionMonitoringDistance)
{
    regionRadius = locationManager.maximumRegionMonitoringDistance;
}

NSString *version = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];
CLRegion * region =nil;

if([version floatValue] >= 7.0f) //for iOS7
{
    region =  [[CLCircularRegion alloc] initWithCenter:centerCoordinate
                                               radius:regionRadius
                                           identifier:identifier];
}
else // iOS 7 below
{
    region = [[CLRegion alloc] initCircularRegionWithCenter:centerCoordinate
                                                   radius:regionRadius
                                               identifier:identifier];
}


region.notifyOnEntry = YES;
region.notifyOnExit = YES;


NSLog(@"region is %@", region);

return  region;


  }

 - (void) initializeRegionMonitoring:(NSArray*)geofences {
     if(![CLLocationManager regionMonitoringAvailable]) {

    return;
}

for(CLRegion *geofence in geofences) {
    [locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:geofence];
}
}


-(BOOL) checkLocationManager
 {
if(![CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled])
{
    [self showMessage:@"You need to enable Location Services"];
    return  FALSE;
}
if(![CLLocationManager isMonitoringAvailableForClass:[CLRegion class]])
{
    [self showMessage:@"Region monitoring is not available for this Class"];
            return  FALSE;
}
if([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] == kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied ||
   [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] == kCLAuthorizationStatusRestricted  )
{
    [self showMessage:@"You need to authorize Location Services for the APP"];
    return  FALSE;
}
return TRUE;
   }
-(void) addGeofence:(NSDictionary*) dict
 {

CLRegion * region = [self dictToRegion:dict];

[arr_region addObject:[self dictToRegion:dict]];

[self initializeRegionMonitoring:arr_region];


[locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:region];
  }
 -(void) findCurrentFence
 {
NSString *version = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];

if([version floatValue] >= 7.0f) //for iOS7
{
    NSArray * monitoredRegions = [locationManager.monitoredRegions allObjects];
    for(CLRegion *region in monitoredRegions)
     {
         [locationManager requestStateForRegion:region];
     }
}
else
{
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

  }
  -(void) removeGeofence:(NSDictionary*) dict
 {
CLRegion * region = [self dictToRegion:dict];
[locationManager stopMonitoringForRegion:region];

 }
-(void) clearGeofences
 {
NSArray * monitoredRegions = [locationManager.monitoredRegions allObjects];
for(CLRegion *region in monitoredRegions) {
    [locationManager stopMonitoringForRegion:region];
}
 }
    /*
    Delegate Methods
     */

    - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
  didDetermineState:(CLRegionState)state forRegion:(CLRegion *)region
   {
if(state == CLRegionStateInside)
{
    NSLog(@"##Entered Region - %@", region.identifier);
}
else if(state == CLRegionStateOutside)
{
    NSLog(@"##Exited Region - %@", region.identifier);
}
else{
    NSLog(@"##Unknown state  Region - %@", region.identifier);
}
  }
  - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didStartMonitoringForRegion:   (CLRegion *)region
{
NSLog(@"Started monitoring %@ region", region.identifier);
 }


  - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region
   {   NSLog(@"Entered Region - %@", region.identifier);


UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];
[notification setAlertBody:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Welcome you have entered geo-fence area"]];
[notification setFireDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:1.0]];
[notification setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone  defaultTimeZone]];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setScheduledLocalNotifications:[NSArray arrayWithObject:notification]];

NSLog(@"Notification is %@",notification);



  }
   - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didExitRegion:(CLRegion *)region
  {   NSLog(@"Exited Region - %@", region.identifier);


UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];
[notification setAlertBody:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Welcome you have entered geo-fence area"]];
[notification setFireDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:1.0]];
[notification setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone  defaultTimeZone]];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setScheduledLocalNotifications:[NSArray arrayWithObject:notification]];

NSLog(@"Notification is %@",notification);


   }


   - (void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
  didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
   {


    NSSet * monitoredRegions = locationManager.monitoredRegions;

     [self locateCurrentGeofenceWithLocation:[locations lastObject]   InMonitoredRegions:monitoredRegions];


[locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];



   }

    - (void) locateCurrentGeofenceWithLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
                    InMonitoredRegions:(NSSet *) monitoredRegions
   {


 NSString *version = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];
 //    if([version floatValue] < 7.0f) // below iOS7
  //    {
    [monitoredRegions enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(CLRegion *region,BOOL *stop)
     {
         NSString *identifer = region.identifier;
         NSLog(@"regions are %@",identifer);
         CLLocationCoordinate2D centerCoords =region.center;
         CLLocationCoordinate2D currentCoords=     CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(newLocation.coordinate.latitude,newLocation.coordinate.longitude);
         CLLocationDistance radius = region.radius;


         NSNumber * currentLocationDistance =[self calculateDistanceInMetersBetweenCoord:currentCoords coord:centerCoords];
         if([currentLocationDistance floatValue] < radius)
         {
             NSLog(@"Invoking didEnterRegion Manually for region: %@",identifer);

             //stop Monitoring Region temporarily
             [locationManager stopMonitoringForRegion:region];

             [self locationManager:locationManager didDetermineState:CLRegionStateInside forRegion:region];
             //start Monitoing Region
             [locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:region];
         }
   //         }];
     }];
   }



     - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager monitoringDidFailForRegion:(CLRegion *)region withError:(NSError *)error
   {


NSLog(@"monitoringDidFailForRegion %@ %@",
      region, error.localizedDescription);
for (CLRegion *monitoredRegion in manager.monitoredRegions) {
    NSLog(@"monitoredRegion: %@", monitoredRegion);
}
if ((error.domain != kCLErrorDomain || error.code != 5) &&
    [manager.monitoredRegions containsObject:region]) {
    NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",
                         region, error.localizedDescription];


    UIAlertView *notificationAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"monitoringDidFailForRegion"
                                                                message:message
                                                               delegate:nil
                                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                                      otherButtonTitles: nil];

    [notificationAlert show];





}
  }
```

Comment: +20 am looking for same from longtime.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to call on main thread.

```
if ([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled])
    {
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateLocation) withObject:self waitUntilDone:NO];
    }


- (void)updateLocation
{
     arr_region=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
     self.locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = NO;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}
```

i hope it helpful.